# Java array min and max issue

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, min

```
package array;
import java.util.*;
public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     int [] a = new int [10];
     Random number = new Random ();
     int x;
      int min, max ;
      min = max = a[0];

for (int b = 0; b<a.length; b++)
   {
       x = number.nextInt (100);
      // System.out.println (x); just for testing x

      a [b]= x;
       System.out.println (a[b]);

       if (a[b] < min) min = a[b];
       if (a[b] > max) max = a[b];
   }

 System.out.println ("Min is: " + min + " " + "Max is: "+ max );
}
}
```

When i set **min = a[0];** and **max = a[0]**, it only returns max value and min is always 0; Can not figure whats wrong. But when I assign values for a[0]..a[9] it works. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well `number.nextInt (100);` will return a number between `0` ans `99`. Since you initialize `min` with `a[0];` (which is is 0 when you created your `int` array), you always get 0 as minimum.

Try to initialise `min` with `min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Comment: Ty that was a problem.

Comment: Ok that solve it. one brief question  so i can  use max = Integer.MIN_Value; for maximum?

Comment: @user3018155 Yes you have to use it. Otherwise if you initialize max with 0 and you have only negative values in your array, you won't get the correct maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only enter positive numbers. For this to work as intended (I assume you want to get the least entered number), initialize min with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

The problem is the following:

`int [] a = new int [10];` will create an array of 10 ints and since the elements are primitive integers they're initialized with 0.

`min = max = a[0];` will subsequently initialize `min` with 0, even though `x = number.nextInt (100);` might later return only numbers greater than 0.

Even initializing `max` with 0 is wrong, if you try to generate negative numbers as well. Thus better initialize `max` with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
min = max = a[0];  // this statement initialize min variable with 0

if (a[b] < min) min = a[b]; // this statement will never execute because your are assigning new value to a[] on each index, even random class generate 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//if (a[b] < min) min = (a[b]);
//the condition is never met because the min value of x is always 0
package array;
import java.util.*;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a = new int [10];
        Random number = new Random ();
        int x;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int b = 0; b<a.length; b++){
            x = number.nextInt (100);
            // System.out.println (x); just for testing x

            a [b]= x;
            System.out.println (a[b]);

            if (a[b] < min) min = a[b];
            if (a[b] > max) max = a[b];
        }

        System.out.println ("Min is: " + min + " " + "Max is: "+ max ); 
}
```